# New install of Firefly wallet crashes when tapping Receive Funds > Share an address, on Android

Tags: android-wallet, firefly, debugging

I'm a newbie to Iota, and just installed the Firefly wallet from the Play store to have a look at it. After creating the wallet with no issues, I tried going into Receive Funds then tapped "Share an address" at which point the app hung for maybe 20 seconds then closed.

I have no urgent intention of using the wallet to receive funds, but I'm also aware that first time user experiences should be of significant interest to the dev community for Iota, and therefore the experience is worth sharing. I'm happy to try out some solutions if provided.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you report this on the official [IOTA Discord](https://discord.iota.org/) or on [GitHub](https://github.com/iotaledger/firefly/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3A%22bug+report%22). The IOTA Stack Exchange community is independent of the IOTA foundation and cannot fix the mobile apps available from the Play Store.

For what it's worth, I can reproduce on my Android 13 phone and can provide the following logcat:

```
D CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 160794467; UID 10302; state: ENABLED
E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: CapacitorPlugins
E AndroidRuntime: Process: org.iota.firefly.mobile, PID: 30881
E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException03-28 23:07:44.321 30881 30962 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.getcapacitor.Bridge.lambda$callPluginMethod$0$Bridge(Bridge.java:601)
E AndroidRuntime:        at com.getcapacitor.-$$Lambda$Bridge$25SFHybyAQk7zS27hTVXh2p8tmw.run(Unknown Source:8)
E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E AndroidRuntime:        at com.getcapacitor.PluginHandle.invoke(PluginHandle.java:121)
E AndroidRuntime:        at com.getcapacitor.Bridge.lambda$callPluginMethod$0$Bridge(Bridge.java:592)
E AndroidRuntime:        ... 6 more
E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.iota.firefly.mobile: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
E AndroidRuntime: Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:404)
E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:674)
E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:661)
E AndroidRuntime:        at com.capacitorjs.plugins.share.SharePlugin.share(SharePlugin.java:115)
E AndroidRuntime:        ... 9 more
I DropBoxManagerService: add tag=data_app_crash isTagEnabled=true flags=0x2
W ActivityTaskManager:   Force finishing activity org.iota.firefly.mobile/.alpha.MainActivity
E FrameEvents: updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
D ActivityTrigger: ActivityTrigger activityPauseTrigger
I ANDR-PERF-ACT-TRIG: activity pause 'org.iota.firefly.mobile/org.iota.firefly.mobile.alpha.MainActivity/35'
I Process : Sending signal. PID: 30881 SIG: 9
W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.stats.service.DropBoxEntryAddedReceiver
W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver
I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{ba0a41c u0 org.iota.firefly.mobile/org.iota.firefly.mobile.alpha.MainActivity}
I ActivityManager: Process org.iota.firefly.mobile (pid 30881) has died: prcp TOP
I Zygote  : Process 30881 exited due to signal 9 (Killed)
W InputManager-JNI: Input channel object 'ba0a41c org.iota.firefly.mobile/org.iota.firefly.mobile.alpha.MainActivity (client)' was disposed without first being removed with the input manager!
I libprocessgroup: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10302 pid 30881 in 0ms
I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{e96014d u0 org.iota.firefly.mobile/org.iota.firefly.mobile.alpha.MainActivity}
W InputManager-JNI: Input channel object 'e96014d org.iota.firefly.mobile/org.iota.firefly.mobile.alpha.MainActivity (client)' was disposed without first being removed with the input manager!
W ActivityManager: Exception when unbinding service org.iota.firefly.mobile/org.chromium.content.app.SandboxedProcessService0:0
W ActivityManager: android.os.DeadObjectException
W ActivityManager:       at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
W ActivityManager:       at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:584)
W ActivityManager:       at android.app.IApplicationThread$Stub$Proxy.scheduleUnbindService(IApplicationThread.java:1346)
W ActivityManager:       at com.android.server.am.ActiveServices.removeConnectionLocked(ActiveServices.java:5086)
W ActivityManager:       at com.android.server.am.ActiveServices.killServicesLocked(ActiveServices.java:5613)
W ActivityManager:       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.cleanUpApplicationRecordLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:12536)
W ActivityManager:       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppDiedLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:3352)
W ActivityManager:       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.appDiedLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:3468)
W ActivityManager:       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$AppDeathRecipient.binderDied(ActivityManagerService.java:1501)
W ActivityManager:       at android.os.IBinder$DeathRecipient.binderDied(IBinder.java:317)
W ActivityManager:       at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(BinderProxy.java:704)
I ActivityManager: Killing 30921:com.google.android.webview:sandboxed_process0:org.chromium.content.app.SandboxedProcessService0:0/u0a302i77 (adj 900): isolated not needed
I libprocessgroup: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 99077 pid 30921 in 0ms
I ANDR-PERF-ACT-TRIG: activity resume 'com.android.launcher3/com.android.searchlauncher.SearchLauncher/33'
W ProcessStats: Tracking association SourceState{a9b6500 system/1000 BTopFgs #1401147} whose proc state 2 is better than process ProcessState{fd02db4 com.google.android.gms.persistent/10107 pkg=com.google.android.gms} proc state 3 (51 skipped)
W WindowManager: Failed to deliver inset state change to w=Window{ba0a41c u0 org.iota.firefly.mobile/org.iota.firefly.mobile.alpha.MainActivity EXITING}
W WindowManager: android.os.DeadObjectException
W WindowManager:         at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
W WindowManager:         at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:584)
W WindowManager:         at android.view.IWindow$Stub$Proxy.insetsControlChanged(IWindow.java:473)
W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowState.notifyInsetsControlChanged(WindowState.java:3994)
W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.InsetsStateController.lambda$notifyPendingInsetsControlChanged$5$com-android-server-wm-InsetsStateController(InsetsStateController.java:348)
W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.InsetsStateController$$ExternalSyntheticLambda4.run(Unknown Source:2)
W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.executeAfterPrepareSurfacesRunnables(WindowAnimator.java:345)
W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.animate(WindowAnimator.java:226)
W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.lambda$new$1$com-android-server-wm-WindowAnimator(WindowAnimator.java:106)
W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.doFrame(Unknown Source:2)
W WindowManager:         at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1317)
W WindowManager:         at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1327)
W WindowManager:         at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:985)
W WindowManager:         at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:911)
W WindowManager:         at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1302)
W WindowManager:         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
W WindowManager:         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W WindowManager:         at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
W WindowManager:         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
W WindowManager:         at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:44)
W WindowManager: Exception thrown during dispatchAppVisibility Window{ba0a41c u0 org.iota.firefly.mobile/org.iota.firefly.mobile.alpha.MainActivity EXITING}
W WindowManager: android.os.DeadObjectException
W WindowManager:         at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
W WindowManager:         at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:584)
W WindowManager:         at android.view.IWindow$Stub$Proxy.dispatchAppVisibility(IWindow.java:536)
W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowState.sendAppVisibilityToClients(WindowState.java:3489)
W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.sendAppVisibilityToClients(WindowContainer.java:1199)
W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowToken.setClientVisible(WindowToken.java:398)
W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.setClientVisible(ActivityRecord.java:6696)
W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.onAnimationFinished(ActivityRecord.java:7492)
W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.postApplyAnimation(ActivityRecord.java:5299)
W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.commitVisibility(ActivityRecord.java:5271)
W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.commitVisibility(ActivityRecord.java:5275)
W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.AppTransitionController.handleClosingApps(AppTransitionController.java:1098)
W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.AppTransitionController.handleAppTransitionReady(AppTransitionController.java:286)
W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.checkAppTransitionReady(RootWindowContainer.java:986)
W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.performSurfacePlacementNoTrace(RootWindowContainer.java:853)
W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.performSurfacePlacement(RootWindowContainer.java:795)
W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer.performSurfacePlacementLoop(WindowSurfacePlacer.java:177)
W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer.performSurfacePlacement(WindowSurfacePlacer.java:126)
W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer.performSurfacePlacement(WindowSurfacePlacer.java:115)
W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer$Traverser.run(WindowSurfacePlacer.java:57)
W WindowManager:         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
W WindowManager:         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W WindowManager:         at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
W WindowManager:         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
W WindowManager:         at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
W WindowManager:         at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:44)
```

Comment: Furthermore, I would like to invite you to submit all this information as an issue on GitHub to ensure that the issue can be tracked effectively.

You can do this by visiting https://github.com/iotaledger/firefly/issues

Thank you both